# Tesseract 3.02 for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ocr, tesseract

i made some googling to make my iOS app faster for OCR (i use tesseract 3.01).
(i downloaded it from here http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/)
i came across some links (

> [How can I make tesseract on iOS faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630640/how-can-i-make-tesseract-on-ios-faster)

)here that say using tesseract 3.02 for OCR. but i couldnt find the link or svn for it.

is there anyone who uses tesseract 3.02 on his/her iOS apps? it would be great if there is sample project.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to my compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVN url is [Tesseract SVN](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)

If you use a SVN software you will download the latest version available, but you have to compile for iOS

BTW, I tested the suzuki script and it works with the lastest version, but it doesn't include some new .h files (6 or 7), so you will need to search for them in the tesseract folfer (they are in the ccutil and ccmain folders)

EDIT: I uploaded my compilation to github, it's a plugin for phonegap, but you can pick the dependencies folder an use it on any regular iOS project.

[OCR Plugin](http://goo.gl/9To23)

Comment: Does it works for ios 6 sdk ? I got a lot of compiling errors when I compiled it in my Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: yes, but you have to test on a real device, it fails on the simulator

Comment: really? I just tried once and failed because there wasn't i386 symbols, but I have compiled new tesseract versions twice after that, maybe I included i386 and don't remember