# In xcode how can I do a real-time scan of the camera preview frame by frame using Tesseract OCR

Tags: ios, camera, real-time, ocr, tesseract

As many of you know Tesseract does character recognition in still photos or images. I'm using xcode for my iOS app and I got this problem. How can I use tesseract to scan the camera live preview. An app that does this is the Word Lens app, it makes a frame by frame live recognition and translation of the text being previewed by the camera. I'm trying to do this live character recognition whithout the translation part. What is the best approach? How can I do a real-time scan of the camera preview frame by frame using Tesseract OCR? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with tesseract, I've tested it and needs some time to recognize a simple image

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it and Performance is too low. Camera output eight pictures per second, but OCR process one need about 2 seconds.

The link [A (quasi-) real-time video processing on iOS](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/23153661857/a-quasi-real-time-video-processing-on-ios-in)

The link [tesseract-ios](https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios)

and [How can I make tesseract on iOS faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630640/how-can-i-make-tesseract-on-ios-faster?rq=1)

Maybe we need use OpenCV.

Comment: Did you try on recent hardware too?

Answer (score -1):

Or, alternative you can use other free product, that does OCR in camera preview: [ABBYY Real-Time Recognition OCR](http://rtrsdk.com).

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.